# Why conj and cons has different arguments order

Tags: clojure

In `conj`, the original collection is the **first argument**, in `cons`, it's the **second argument**.

I'm new to clojure, this seems a bit confusing. This two function has similar behavior, but why is the arguments order different, is it purposely designed like this?

```
(conj '(1 2 3) 4)
; => (4 1 2 3)

(cons 4 '(1 2 3))
; => (4 1 2 3)
```

---

I know this two functions are different, but why `conj` and `cons` place the original collection in different argument order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`cons`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) traditionally means construct new object prepending first arg into second, and thats how the args are ordered.

Here's quote from LISP cons,

> In LISP jargon, the expression "to cons x onto y" means to construct a
>   new object with `(cons x y)`

But `conjoin` normally is to append on given data-structure *but depends on clojure data-type you use.* Thats why collection comes first and then element to append.

Lets see the `Vector`;

```
user=> (type [3 5 7 11])
clojure.lang.PersistentVector

user=> (cons 1 [3 5 7 11])
(1 3 5 7 11)

user=> (conj [3 5 7 11] 13)
[3 5 7 11 13]
```

But for `List`, `conjoin` prepends as well,

```
user=> (type '(3 5 7 11))
clojure.lang.PersistentList

user=> (cons 1 '(3 5 7 11))
(1 3 5 7 11)

user=> (conj '(3 5 7 11) 13)
(13 3 5 7 11)
```

The [doc for `conj`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj) describes that as well.

```
user=> (doc conj)
-------------------------
clojure.core/conj
([coll x] [coll x & xs])
  conj[oin]. Returns a new collection with the xs
    'added'. (conj nil item) returns (item).  The 'addition' may
    happen at different 'places' depending on the concrete type.
nil
```

The order applies to any other functional languages as far as I know. Here's in scala;

```
scala> 1 +: Seq(1, 3, 5)
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 1, 3, 5)

scala> Seq(1, 3, 5) :+ 7
res2: Seq[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 7)
```

Comment: Note: `conj` is very much like an operation, ie the data type needs to support it. `cons` on the other hand doesn't operate on the seq, it will happily take ANYTHING that is seqable. Ie, you can do `(cons 1 "abc")` or `(cons 1 (into-array [1 2]))`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer gives a nice overview.  I also wanted to point out the types resulting from `conj` and `cons`:

```
(cons 1 [2 3])          => <#clojure.lang.Cons (1 2 3)>
(conj [2 3] 9)          => <#clojure.lang.PersistentVector [2 3 9]>

(cons 1 (quote (2 3)))  => <#clojure.lang.Cons (1 2 3)>
(conj (quote (2 3)) 9)  => <#clojure.lang.PersistentList (9 2 3)>
```

The type `clojure.lang.Cons` is a sequential type similar to (but not identical to) a `clojure.lang.PersistentList`:

```
(supers clojure.lang.Cons) => 
  #{ clojure.lang.ASeq 
     clojure.lang.IHashEq 
     clojure.lang.IMeta 
     clojure.lang.IObj 
     clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection 
     clojure.lang.ISeq 
     clojure.lang.Obj 
     clojure.lang.Seqable 
     clojure.lang.Sequential 
     java.io.Serializable 
     java.lang.Iterable
     java.lang.Object 
     java.util.Collection 
     java.util.List }
```

To simplify adding to the beginning or end of a sequence, [you may be interested in the functions `append` and `prepend`.](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#adding-values-to-the-beginning-or-end-of-a-sequence)

Answer (score -1):

Briefly, because they are opposite. In cons, the target element is the first one, and a collection becomes a the rest of the result sequence. In conj, the target element becomes a tail of the final collection.

I may recommend you to read the first chapter of SICP where cons and `consing` terms are described quite well.